# ELK integration with Laravel

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, logstash, laravel-8, elk

I am very beginner to ELK, I have developed an application in Laravel with Mysql backend.

Now, I would like to integrate the Elastic search with the existing app & if the user updates anything on the app then it should reflect immediately on the Elastic search.

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1):

ELK integration into your application will require few steps before even that you must decide how/where you want to run the es and kb etc. There a some options available. You can create your self managed instances in VMs in that case you may use the docker images for kb , es etc.
Elastic offers ECK (Elastic Cloud on K8s) you could install the ECK operator in a K8s environment and that will also spin up kibana and elasticsearch for you.

Assuming that your app is running in localhost:

1. Configure and deploy elasticsearch edit elasticsearch.yaml.
2. Configure and deploy kibana edit kibana.yaml.
3. Configure beats / logstash (filebeat.yaml) to forward the logs to elasticsearch endpoint for indexing.
4. Once your log forwarder is running and sending logs to ES , you can visualize them in kb.

Hope this gives you some background.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @pindropviolence. I would like to setup it into the localhost. The problem is how the ES will know if the user made any updates on the application.

Comment: Hi - For monoring your DB. The logstash pipeline instance with JDBC input plugin (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html) will be able to monitor your DB , tables. If there are any transactions then that will be shipped to ES by Logstash. You could also do many other things with logstash like processing , gorking etc. For a simple usecase if you want to monitor your application then use filebeat to read the app log files and ship them to ES. In the filebeat.yaml you will need to configure it to read app log files which will be shipped to ES.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating an Observer of Models.

When an entry is created or updated with Model Eloquent query at that time the particular Model Observer run and you can set dispatch job for elastic search from observer functions.

And from job execution, you will get an entry of that record inside the Elastic search job and from there you will add or update particular data along with MySQL DB synchronized.

Example :
You need to setup Observer inside **app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php** for use this methods.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Blog;
use App\Observers\BlogObserver;
use Elastic\Elasticsearch\Client;
use Elastic\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

        $this->app->singleton(Client::class, function () {
            return ClientBuilder::create()
                ->setHosts(['127.0.0.1:9200'])
                // ->setHosts(config('elasticsearch.hosts'))
                ->build();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blog::observe(BlogObserver::class);
    }
}
```

Suppose you have **Blog Model**.

**Blog.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class Blog
 * @property integer $id
 * @property boolean $is_active
 * @property Carbon $publish_date
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $content
 * @property array $category
 * @property string $author
 */
class Blog extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'is_active',
        'publish_date',
        'title',
        'content',
        'category',
        'author',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'is_active',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'is_active' => 'boolean',
        'category' => 'array',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'publish_date',
    ];
}
```

You have your **app\Observers\BlogObserver.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Jobs\IndexBlogElasticsearchJob;
use App\Models\Blog;

class BlogObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the Blog "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Blog  $blog
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Blog $blog)
    {
        dispatch(new IndexBlogElasticsearchJob($blog));
    }

    /**
     * Handle the Blog "updated" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Blog  $blog
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(Blog $blog)
    {
        dispatch(new IndexBlogElasticsearchJob($blog));
    }

    /**
     * Handle the Blog "restored" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Blog  $blog
     * @return void
     */
    public function restored(Blog $blog)
    {
        if ($blog->is_active) {
            dispatch(new IndexBlogElasticsearchJob($blog));
        }
    }
}
```

You have job file for elastic search changes inside **app\Jobs\IndexBlogElasticsearchJob.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Blog;
use Elastic\Elasticsearch\Client;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class IndexBlogElasticsearchJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $blog;

    /**
     * IndexBlogElasticsearchJob constructor.
     * @param Blog $blog
     */
    public function __construct(Blog $blog)
    {
        $this->blog = $blog;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     * @param Client $client
     */
    public function handle(Client $client)
    {
        $params = [
            'index' => 'blogs',
            'id' => $this->blog->id,
            'body' => $this->blog->toArray(),
        ];

        $client->index($params);
    }
}
```